# Batch insert of data into a table

Tags: sql-server

I have very big dataset about 40000000 items of data. I am trying to load this to a new table. Since the dataset is really big, I am trying to load them in batch so the log transaction would not be full. I am using the query below but still have issue with log transaction being full.

Is there a way to commit the transition after each batch so that it wont be saved in log and will go for next batch?

Please let me know if there is a way for me to solve this issue.

And SSIS is not an option for me currently.

```
DECLARE @I BIGINT;    
DECLARE @icnt int;   
DECLARE @n INT, @flag INT;   

SELECT @icnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) A  

PRINT @ICNT  
BEGIN  
    SELECT @I = 0  

    WHILE @I <=@icnt  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT @n = 0  
        SELECT @flag = 1  

        BEGIN TRANSACTION  
        WHILE @flag != 0  
        BEGIN  
            ;WITH A AS   
            (
                SELECT
                    a.*,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS batchnum 
                FROM 
                    table1       
            )   
            INSERT INTO table2 (*)  
                SELECT *   
                FROM A
                WHERE batchnum >= @I AND batchnum <@I + 10000000  

            SELECT @I = @I + 10000000  
            SELECT @n = @n + 10000000

            SELECT @flag = CASE WHEN @n >= 50000000 THEN 0   
                                WHEN @I >= @icnt THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
            PRINT @I  
        END   

        COMMIT TRANSACTION  
    END   
END
```

Comment: This is not practical. you should partition your table and use partition switch to transfer data (if possible). BTW. event if you commit transaction, the transaction log will not be discarded immediately. so it's not gonna be the solution.

Comment: In addition to Flicker's suggestion, you could set your database to SIMPLE recovery right before the transfer, and then set it back to FULL afterwards.